# Suggestion for an answering event

Tags: discussion

Recently, Chemi Stack exchange had an "old unanswered questions' answering event". Can't we have something like this for our site ? We could especially take those questions whose answers are in the comments. What say ?

It would be a great learning experience and lots of fun too!

Answer (score 3):

I would appreciate this (I am going through there as well). The problem is that in many cases additional questions were asked for clarification and these were often never answered. Which makes writing a good answer difficult.

The question is, if these orphan questions should then stay here on the board.

Comment: If a question is not answerable, it should be closed. Closing questions should be part of such an event.