# Unanswered question event- level 2

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions, event

Sort of a revival of [this](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/642/old-unanswered-question-event) post.

**UPDATE on 24th Nov 2014**

```
6,676   questions
8,489   answers
86%     answered
1.5     Q/A ratio
7,333   users
9,071   visitors/day
12.2    questions/day
425     avid users
7,333   total users
```

So it seems we have improved. But there still are many unanswered questions. I think this is the right time to do this exercise again. Improve the site before the vacations :)

Many questions are answerable. Close or flag questions in which the OP has not responded to comments asking for clarification. For really unanswerable questions see [this](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/763/what-is-to-be-done-with-questions-that-have-no-answers-yet) post.

For really niche questions I would request the OP to post the answer themselves if they have found one.

We have to beat the chemistry guys ;)

Comment: Thanks for tallying this up. You guys are on the right track!

Comment: Close to 30 closures today. Good going.

Comment: We got down from 810 unanswered questions this morning to 783 at the moment.

Comment: Chemistry guy here, randomly browsing SE:Biology. I got a chuckle at that last statement.

Comment: @JohnSnow Whats your point?

Comment: @Chris Is it a good idea to remind OPs to accept answers?

Comment: @WYSIWYG We could do that (and I sometimes do it), it's a nice gesture towards the person who writes an answer. The problem is that many people who ask questions are not regulary on the site...

Comment: We`re up to 88%.

Comment: I want to add that we upvote answers for the questions with answers but with zero votes if they have shown some effort and are useful. There are many like that (~70). Search last pages of unanswered questions.

Comment: Now gone up to 89%.

Comment: We are 90% now :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update** as on 12/12/2014:

```
6,826   questions
8,728   answers
90%     answered     **
1.4     Q/A ratio
7,518   users
430     avid users   **
8,314   visitors/day
12      questions/day
```

There are some fluctuating metrics such as visits/day etc but I guess overall there has been a great improvement; especially the answered percentage — a 4% up (86→90%) in 2 weeks. This is quite commendable and we have worked hard at it; congratulations to everyone. It also seems that we have 5 more avid users; this is great.

So lets get to the other side of 90 and try to get more and better questions. We would also want more avid users- so just ask your colleagues and friends to get in :)

PS: I would like if Abby Hairboat gives their opinion on this. Perhaps with a good news that we are up for evaluation :)

Comment: We have gone to 91% :)